# Syntax error near ´╗┐

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to restore a database in MySQL from a txt file.

Txt file:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: labb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.0.45-community-nt

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `bil`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bil`;
CREATE TABLE `bil` (
  `regnr` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `marke` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `farg` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `agare` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`regnr`),
  KEY `FK_bilagare` (`agare`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_bilagare` FOREIGN KEY (`agare`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bil`
--

LOCK TABLES `bil` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bil` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `bil` VALUES ('ABC123','VOLVO','blå',1),('BCD234','SAAB','gul',2),('CDE451','FIAT','svart',3),('FFF333','NISSAN','grön',4),('GGH011','AUDI','svart',17),('GGH445','DODGE','brun',6),('JGR344','FIAT','svart',8),('KFS929','FIAT','brun',16),('KGB654','VOLVO','brun',15),('KOOL01','VOLVO','svart',12),('KRF799','AUDI','blå',7),('OKS555','SAAB','vit',18),('OOD001','FIAT','röd',10),('PAD902','NISSAN','grå',10),('PED900','SAAB','grön',13),('RFN754','MERCEDES','svart',19),('SLL989','SAAB','svart',13),('TJJ675','NISSAN','silver',9),('TYY764','NISSAN','vit',14),('UFF220','PEUGEOT','gul',18),('UUU110','PEUGEOT','vit',7);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bil` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `person`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `person`;
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fnamn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `enamn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `stad` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `person`
--

LOCK TABLES `person` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `person` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `person` VALUES (1,'Lina','Karlsson','Stockholm'),(2,'Lena','Svensson','Lund'),(3,'Lisa','Fredriksson','Uppsala'),(4,'Maria','Bergström','Umeå'),(5,'Karin','Sjödahl','Lund'),(6,'Kristina','Boström','Stockholm'),(7,'Pia','Bengtsson','Stockholm'),(8,'Ulrika','Alfredsson','Lund'),(9,'Maria','Berglund','Stockholm'),(10,'Sara','Ling','Uppsala'),(11,'Kerstin','Kruger','Stockholm'),(12,'Christina','Lambert','Göteborg'),(13,'Greta','Westin','Göteborg'),(14,'Gustav','Westman','Stockholm'),(15,'Peter','Thor','Stockholm'),(16,'Peter','Nordlund','Lund'),(17,'Harald','Olsson','Stockholm'),(18,'Lars-Erik','Pettersson','Göteborg'),(19,'Alexander','Sederlind','Örebro');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `person` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2007-09-01 17:29:18
```

My current MySQL commands and results:

```
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 19
Server version: 5.1.73-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> \. /Users/myusername/Desktop/Lab/labbdb.txt
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '´╗┐





/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */' at line 1
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What is currently going on here? How are you suppose to restore this script?

Comment: Load the file in your favourite text editor and remove the UTF-8 BOM

Comment: Now it won't complain about syntax error, but it still says that there is no database selected.

Comment: Then [select one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html).

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `´╗┐` symbols appear to be a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) misinterpreted as CP850 characters (the default Windows code page in Western Europe). Since the BOM is neither mandatory nor recommended you can just strip it.